# Apache 2.4 and iis 7.5 with diff ip's on server 2008r2

Tags: apache, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I am running a .asp site on iis 7.5 on one ip and everything is working fine.

I installed wamp and set everything up (or so I thought) and locally everything works, but remotely I get a timeout.

The changes I have made are as follows:

- Used netsh http to force iis to listen on ip#1 and only ip#1
- edited HTTPD.conf to include ip#2 and use httpd-vhosts as follows:

  ```
   Listen ip#2:80
   Listen 80
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
  ```
- Added virtual host for wampserver localhost and the second site in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```html
<VirtualHost ip#2:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  <Directory "D:/wamp/www">
    AllowOverride All
    <IfDefine APACHE24>
      Require local
    </IfDefine>
    <IfDefine !APACHE24>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all 
      Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    </IfDefine>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost ip#2:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/www.citieswestpub.xyz" 
  ServerName www.citieswestpub.xyz 
  ServerAlias www.citieswestpub.xyz
</VirtualHost>
```

-Lastly I edited the hosts file to include the new site:

```
   ip#2 www.citieswestpub.xyz
   ip#2 citieswestpub.xyz
```

The IIS site works fine. www.phgmag.com It has worked during the whole process.

The Apache site (www.citieswestpub.xyz) times out with no errors, and no apache log errors - Which is telling me I'm not hitting Apache?

I did change DNS too (forgot to mention that) and the ip is propagated.

Can anyone see something I'm missing, or just plain screwed up?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Actually I misspoke- The access log is showing this when I browse remotely to the apache site: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21

Answer (score 0):

Based on your scenario, you should NOT have "Listen 80" because you only want "Listen ip#2:80".

Comment: So I commented out Listen 80 with no change, but my access log now reads: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4868. Not sure what (If anything) that means